# Error when installing pip for python2.7

Tags: linux, python, pip

I have installed python2.7 on Linux and I want to install **pip** under `/path/to/python2.7.9/bin`. So I did this:

```
> cd /path/to/setuptools-16.0
> /path/to/python2.7.9/bin/python setup.py install
> cd /path/to/pip-7.0.0
> /path/to/python2.7.9/bin/python setup.py install
```

Then **pip** is installed under `/path/to/python2.7.9/bin`. But when I executed `/path/to/python2.7.9/bin/pip`, it shows:

```
> ~/local/python-2.7.9/bin/pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2381, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2087, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/root/local/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts'
```

I have tried installing a lot of packages, like *distribute*, *scripts*. But no help.

I don't know what is wrong. Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and could solve it by adding the libssl-dev package. On Debian-based distributions you can install the package via apt-get:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get -y install libssl-dev
```

**Update:**
If the libssl-dev packages is not available for your distro, you can use the openssl-dev package instead. For example on Alpine Linux:

```
$ apk --update add openssl-dev
```